# Tabulate problem with \VL

Tags: context

All,

I have an ancient Context document that I've been using for years. It starts with:

```
\startcomponent  PizzaProblems-03
\project         PizzaProblems
\product         fall15

\assignment[
      title=Pizza and Problems,
     course=Fall 2015,
   assigned={d=3,m=12,y=2015},
        due={d=3,m=12,y=2015}]

\pdfmapline{=cmsy10 LMMathSymbols10-Italic "enclmmathsy ReEncodeFont"
<lm-mathsy.enc  <lmsy10.pfb }

\usemodule[newmat]
\usemodule[tikz]
```

Now I am trying to do a table. What I want is a table with three rows and three columns, with these entries:

50 b c

d  e f

g  h 2

And I want it completely framed. I am reading how to do tabulate, but when I try this from the documentation with the \VL command:

```
\starttabulate[||||] 
    \NC test \VL test \VL test \VL\NR 
    \VL test \NC test \VL test \VL\NR 
    \VL test \VL test \NC test \VL\NR 
    \VL test \VL test \VL test \NC\NR 
\stoptabulate
```

I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\tabulatecontent ->\NC test \VL
```

Can someone give me some help on this?

Comment: Works here with ConTeXt MkIV `2015.10.09`. However, if you are starting from scratch, I would suggest that you use the Natural Table environment rather than `tabulate`.

Comment: @Aditya Thanks for the answer. I'll try updating and looking at the Natural Table environment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op solved it by his own but does not tell us how ...